# If there is a value with the same key on one side of the object, merge

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, ecmascript-6, frontend

If there is data with the same key in one of the other State Objects, I want to overwrite it.

Here's an example:

As you can see from the code, if there are content1, content2, and the key values ​​in content1 and content2 are the same, I want to change it to the content2 coin value.

```
console.log(content1) 
[
    {
        key: 1,
        coin:0
    },
    {
        key: 2, 
        coin: 0
    },
    {
        key: 3, 
        coin: 0
    },
]
```

```
console.log(content2) 
[
    {
        key: 2,
        coin: 400
    }
]
```

The result I want is this:

```
console.log(content1) 

[
    {
        key: 1,
        coin:0
    },
    {
        key: 2, 
        coin: 400
    },
    {
        key: 3, 
        coin: 0
    },
]
```

I've tried using the `map` and `find` functions by myself, but I can't solve it by myself, so I'm asking a question.

Comment: please add your tries.

Comment: btw, how many data do you have in `content2`?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use forEach method, to iterate over the `content2` array, then for each item try to find it's equivalent key in the `content1` array, and if there, you can update the coin directly

```js
const content1 = [
    {
        key: 1,
        coin:0
    },
    {
        key: 2, 
        coin: 0
    },
    {
        key: 3, 
        coin: 0
    },
]

const content2 = [
    {
        key: 2,
        coin: 400
    }
]

// here you loop throw the `content2` to find an item in `content1` equal it's key value.
content2.forEach(item => {
  const itemInContent1 = content1.find(i => i.key === item.key);
  
  // if there is an item has the same key, set the coin value to the `item` value.
  if (itemInContent1) {
    itemInContent1.coin = item.coin
  }
})

console.log(content1)
```

Comment: When you try button onClick, you need to write it in the onClick event function, but if you use forEach inside onClick, it will not change.

Comment: It will work normally with click event function, but if you are working with react, and you update the `state`, Yes you need to update the array refereance to update the `state`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) over here to store the coins so that you don't have to loop over again and again

```js
const arr1 = [
    {
        key: 1,
        coin: 0,
    },
    {
        key: 2,
        coin: 0,
    },
    {
        key: 3,
        coin: 0,
    },
];

const arr2 = [
    {
        key: 2,
        coin: 400,
    },
];

const map = new Map();
arr2.forEach(({ key, coin }) => map.set(key, coin));

const result = arr1.map(({ key, coin }) => ({
    key,
    coin: coin + (map.get(key) ?? 0),
}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce function can be used for this operation something like below:

```js
let arr1 = [
    {
        key: 1,
        coin: 0,
    },
    {
        key: 2,
        coin: 0,
    },
    {
        key: 3,
        coin: 0,
    },
];

let arr2 = [
    {
        key: 2,
        coin: 400,
    },
];

arr1 = arr1.concat(arr2).reduce((a, b) => {
    let idx = a.findIndex((x) => x.key == b.key);
    if (idx != -1) {
        a.fill(b, idx, idx + 1);
    } else {
        a.push(b);
    }
    return a;
}, []);
console.log(arr1);
```